# EF6 EntityCommand get parameters and performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In a EF6 context, I want to filter multiples entities by dynamic fields/attributes. I'm new to EF and my perspective is very corrupted by T-SQL and stored procedures and dynamic SQL queries.

For instance in a ERP environment, the user can filter by a code, and the system should return the:

- Customer with CustomerID = code
- Supplier with SupplierID = code
- User with UserID = code
- Orders with CustomerID/SupplierID = code
- etc.

But can not only be a code, can multiples concepts to filter for: a name, a city, a date, ... and may all not apply to all the entities.

So since each entity has different attributes names to refer to that "code" concept, I've thought that the best solution is to use EntityCommand instead of LinQ.

And the code should look something like:

```
// Create a query that takes two parameters.
string eSqlCustomerQuery =
    @"SELECT VALUE Contact FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Customer AS Customer";
string eSqlCustomerQuery =
    @"SELECT VALUE Contact FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Customer AS Customer";
// Create a list of parameters
var param = new SortedList<string, EntityParameter>();

// for each clauses add a pamater and build the query command dynamically.
if(!code)
{
    eSqlCustomerQuery += "WHERE Customer.CustomerID = @CODE";
    eSqlSupplierQuery += "WHERE Supplier.SupplierID = @CODE";
    //... more entities to 
    param["CODE"].ParameterName = "CODE";
    param["CODE"].Value = code;
}
// more parameters here...

using (EntityConnection conn =
    new EntityConnection("name=AdventureWorksEntities"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (EntityCommand cmd = new EntityCommand(eSqlCustomerQuery, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param["CODE"]);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param["DATE"]);
        // more parameters here...
    }
    // the same for each query...
    // ...
    // run all the queries ...
    // ...
    // Etc.
    conn.Close();
}
```

My questions are 3:

- **At the time I'm doing `cmd = new EntityCommand(eSqlCustomerQuery, conn)` can I use something like the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);`?**
- **Since this dynamic query it's so dynamic that it can be cached or have a reusable execution plan, how can it be improved?**
- **Is it possible to do it with LinQ in a cleaner way?**

Comment: You can create dynamic linq queries. These should be cached. See an example of doing this in my blog post: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/03/24/hacking-linq-to-entities-with-expressions-part-1-really-generic-repository/

Comment: You _can_ build queries dynamically with [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). A great advantage is that you haven't got all these unmaintainable string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ like that:

```
//define base LINQ
Contracts = from R in AdventureWorks.Customer select R; //there is IQueryable, not actually     materialized

//tune filters, no records will fetched
Result = Contracts;
if (code!=null) Result = Result.Where(_=>_.Code==code);
if (date!=null) Result = Result.Where(_=>_.Date==date);

//materialize records
Records = Result..Select(_=>_.Contract).ToArray();
```